How to understand the bytes the stack pointer changed when call function
I feel confused about the bytes the stack pointer changes when callq or retq is invoked?
Here’s a little example
;  Disassembly of leaf (long y) y in %rdi
0000000000400540 <leaf>:
400540: 48 8d 47 02   lea 0x2 (%rdi) ,%rax ; L1: y+2
400544:с3 retq                             ; L2: Return

0000000000400545 <top>:
;  Disassembly of top(long x) x in %rdi
400545: 48 83 ef 05 sub $0x5,%rdi          ; T1: x-5
400549: e8 f2 ff ff ff callq 400540 <leaf> ; T2: Call leaf (x-5)
40054e: 48 01 c0 add %rax,%rax             ; T3: Double result
400551: с3 retq                            ; T4: Return

;  Call to top from function main
40055b: e8 e5 ff ff ff callq 400545 <top>  ; M1: Call top (100)
400560:48 89 c2 mov %rax,%rdx              ; M2: Resume

       Pc             %rdi   %rax      %rsp           *%rsp 

M1  0×400556   callq   100         0x7fffffffe820
T1  0×400545   sub     100         0x7fffffffe818    0х400560
T2  0×400549   callq    95         0x7fffffffe818    0×400560
L1  0×400540   lea      95         0x7fffffffe810    0x40054e
L2  0×400544   retq            97  0x7fffffffe810    0x40054e
T3  0x40054e   add             97  0x7fffffffe818    0×400560
T4  0x400551   Retq           194  0x7fffffffe818    0×400560
M2  0x400560   Mov            194  0x7fffffffe820

Why the stack pointer sub 2 bytes when the first function is called,yet sub 8bytes  when the second is called
I want to know the reason why the difference about the two,when I meet the situation next time,how can I know the number of the bytes the stack pointer changes.

It does not sub 2 bytes. It's in hexa, so going from 0x20 to 0x18 requires subtracting 8, not 2. (if it would subtract only two, the result would end 0x1E)
0x7fffffffe820 = 140737488349216
0x7fffffffe818 = 140737488349208 (-8)
0x7fffffffe810 = 140737488349200 (-8)

